# Django: How to display errors in a custom action?

Tags: django, django-admin

What's the best practice for displaying an error message for errors that occurred in a custom action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use messages framework. The description is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/)

in custom action you just use

```
messages.info(request, 'Message')
```

Answer (score 1):

add an error message to the contrib messages app? It will be displayed at the top of the page on next request/ next page the user sees. Be sure to set the message type as error. Also, be sure to run the action in a transaction and roll it back on error.